# AutoMapper Flattening out nested json

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

Im in the process of trying to flatten out a json result using Automapper but I'm getting an error telling me: `Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping`

In my project I have both AutoMapper & AutoMapper dependency Injection packages installed.

My Startup.cs has the following call:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
}
```

I've set up my mapping profile as follows:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<JiraTicket, JiraDto>();
    }
}
```

The model I want to flatten and the DTO is should flatten to:

```
public class JiraTicket
{
    [Key]
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; } 
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; } 
    public JiraTicketFields fields { get; set; }
}
public class JiraDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Creator { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Self { get; set; }
}
```

Most of the DTO variables are in the `JiraTicketFields.

Finally I'm making a call to my repo with the following lines of code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<JiraDto>> GetAll()
{
    var tickets =  _jiraRepo.GetAll().ToList();
    var result = (IEnumerable<JiraDto>)_mapper.Map<JiraDto>(tickets);
    return result;
}
```

Its when my project hits the `var result...` line that the error is thrown. What is it that I'm missing in this?

Comment: Is your MappingProfile and Startup in the same assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a Profile that tells Automapper how to convert a single `JiraTicket` to a single `JiraDto`, but I think the problem is that you are trying to map a `IEnumerable<JiraTicket>` to a single `JiraDto`, and Automapper doesn't know how to do that.

What you probably want to do (if I understand correctly) is to map a `IEnumerable<JiraTicket>` to a `IEnumerable<JiraDto>`. Then, you would have to do this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<JiraDto>> GetAll()
{
    var tickets =  _jiraRepo.GetAll().ToList();
    var result = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<JiraDto>>(tickets);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this to convert List of JiraTickets to IEnumerable of JiraDtos

```
var result = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<JiraDto>>(tickets);
```

Casting in AutoMapper is done via generics parameter, not via explicit casting